# Get part of a picture in Android?

Tags: android, image, selection, crop

I have created a rectangle to select a part of a picture. An example:
Picture size: 800x600 pixel
Rectangle size: 100x100 pixel
Rectangle position: left: 40px, right: 140px, top: 120px, bottom: 220px

How can I create the image which is inside the rectangle? The image size should be 100x100 pixel. Are there methods or do I have to create a new image by reading out the pixels of the old image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a useful factory method that extracts smaller bitmap from bigger one:

```
Bitmap part = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x,  y, width, height, null, true);
```

In your case,

```
Bitmap part = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, left, top, right-left, bottom-top, null, true);
```

should work.